# String date format convert to date

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, date

I need to convert this string to `yyyy-MM-dd` date format:

```
December 31, 2014 to 2014-12-31
May 31 , 2018 to 2018-05-31
```

Any suggestion?
Regards!

Comment: `2018-2018-31`?

Comment: So what you need is to parse a `varchar` and get a `date` type? Or convert that to yet another `varchar` with the `yyyy-mm-dd` format?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can just use `convert()`:

```
select convert(date, 'December 31, 2014')
```

SQL Server is pretty good about doing such conversions.

So this works in both cases:

```
select convert(date, datestr)
from (values ('December 31, 2014'), ('May 31 , 2018')) v(datestr);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use as shown [Here](http://www.smallsql.de/doc/sql-functions/system/convert.html)

```
Select cast('December 31, 2014' as date) as [Date]
Select cast('December 31, 2014' as date) as [Date]
```

or in higher version of SQL Server provide format string value for different date format as you want.

```
SELECT FORMAT(cast('December 31, 2014' as Date),'yyyy-MM-dd','en-US') AS[DATE IN US FORMAT]
```